# Ms Access, double click listbox element to update form

Tags: forms, ms-access, listbox

I'm trying to make an improved search text field in a form in Access. I'm searching through my customer names and I've been able to implement a "search as you type" textbox linked to a listbox where the matching records show up.

Now I want to simply double click on an item in the listbox and have all the fields of the form update automatically. I am pretty sure it already exists, but I havn't been able to find it. I'd be glad to be pointed to an existing resource or anything.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the listbox's `On Dbl Click` event, click the button and choose code builder.

Then you will need to write some code to figure out which row of the listbox is selected. Use the `.ItemData` method of your listbox. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820776.aspx)

This will return the value in the bound column of your listbox, which you can use to tell the form to navigate to the record that matches that bound column value. You may want to use a `DLOOKUP` to find the Record ID if the listbox bound column is not the primary key. Then you navigate to the record. For that you will likely need the `.FindRecord` method. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835361.aspx)

Comment: .ItemData solved it for me. Thanks!
For the rest of your answer, however, I tried to understand .FindRecord, and failed lol. I will use DAO, SQL and rst.Fields("FieldX") for every field of the form to update.
I was hoping for a simpler solution, but it will work in the end

Comment: Yeah that's probably not the easiest way to do it, but it all depends on the code you write. So you are able to capture the selected row from the listbox, but you haven't been able to navigate to that record on your bound form, correct? Can you edit your question to include the code you wrote using `.ItemData`?